# InfoPath Web Part sends blank value to List view WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, infopath

I would like to use a value (in a dropdown) from an Infopath web part (list form) to send a filter value to list view webpart. I have added a button to send data to webpart, I've also tried included this rule on the drop down. I feel like I've tried all the settings and such, but the Infopath webpart always sends "empty" value to the list view webpart. It doesn't want to send the value in my dropdown, just send empty every time. I have send first row of data unchecked, and send data when page loads is also unchecked. Is this even possible? Or am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure the rule on the Button is "Send data to Web Part".

[image]

Then connect the list view web part with InfoPath form web part as shown below:

[image]
Configure the connection settings:

[image]

Simple demo for your reference:

[image]

Comment: so I followed your instructions exactly (thank you, they are perfect) but I still only get an "empty" filter on the consumer field in the list view webpart after I hit the button to send to webpart. The field in question is a lookup, do you think that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this won't work for me as I'm using a lookup field, between InfoPath and SPD, I have created a hidden helper field to just show the value from SO number, which I will use to connect the InfoPath WebPart and the List view Webpart.